# AutocompleteActivity throw IllegalStateException when startActivityForResult is used

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using `'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'` with Autocomplete :

```
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                    AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY,
                    asList(fields )).build(getActivity());
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

Where fields is a list of Place fields...
Sometimes, AutocompleteActivity is throwing the following errors (Android 6.0.1 only)

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find caller. startActivityForResult should be used.
       at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzfp.zzb(zzfp.java:11)
       at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity.onCreate(AutocompleteActivity.java:8)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2479)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Looking at the AutocompleteActivity#onCreate() method, the following check is failing :

```
this.getCallingActivity() != null
```

But the doc does not indicates use case where calling activity is `null` when `startActivityForResult` is used :

```
/**
 * Return the name of the activity that invoked this activity.  This is
 * who the data in {@link #setResult setResult()} will be sent to.  You
 * can use this information to validate that the recipient is allowed to
 * receive the data.
 *
 * <p class="note">Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it
 * did not use the {@link #startActivityForResult}
 * form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be
 * null.
 *
 * @return The ComponentName of the activity that will receive your
 *         reply, or null if none.
 */
@Nullable
public ComponentName getCallingActivity()
```

Does someone knows about a corner case of the Activity lifecycle in **android 6.0.1** where callingActivity forgets about the use of `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: I am facing same issue in Android 4.4 (API 19), found no solution yet.

Comment: Problem solved in my case, calling activity's **launch_mode** was set to **singleInstance** and getCallingActivity() returns null on pre-lolipop devices, so i added a new activity (non-singleInstance) and fired places intent from there.